# Adding up hash tables in Python

Tags: python, hashtable, addition

I need to add two hash tables in python. However, "+" does not do that:

```
d1={1:1}
d2={1:2,2:5}
d3=d1+d2
```

I need d3={1:3,2:5}.
I appreciate any suggestion.

Answer (score 2):

Use `collections.Counter`:

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> Counter(d1) + Counter(d2)
Counter({2: 5, 1: 3})
```